# Scrapy Python cant crawl href link from a class

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, response, href

Im trying to get for a project the href Link but I didn't get the output on python

[Picture of the Structure from the href i want to crawl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz6c3.png)

I Tried to crawl it with:

```
response.css('a.cr_moreReviewsButton.p_btn100--2nd.cr_js_customReviewPageLink ::attr(href)').extract()
```

and with:

```
for linkhref in response.xpath("//a[@class='cr_moreReviewsButton.p_btn100-2nd.cr_js_customReviewPageLink']/@href"):
hrefpage = linkhref.extract()
```

Does someone have an another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Its because there are spaces in the class name.

Try

```
for linkhref in response.xpath(
    "//a[contains(@class,'cr_moreReviewsButton p_btn100--2nd cr_js_customerReviewPageLink')]/@href"
):
hrefpage = linkhref.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor error in the response.css....

`use get() or getall() func` instead of `extract` to extract the response.

```
response.css('a.cr_moreReviewsButton.p_btn100--2nd.cr_js_customReviewPageLink ::attr(href)').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xp = "//a[contains(@class,'moreReviewsButton') or contains(@class,'customerReviewPageLink')]"
for linkhref in response.xpath(xp):
    hrefpage = linkhref.xpath("./@href").get()
```

Add multiple contains(@class,'-some-value-'), this works most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the Help, i solved it with selenium where i let the driver crawl the href

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).